# Android RecyclerView IllegalArgumentException: called detach on an already detached child ViewHolder

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, illegalargumentexception

I am getting following error sometime (not every time) while updating recycler adapter.

Note : I am using [RecyclerViewMergeAdapter](https://github.com/martijnvdwoude/recycler-view-merge-adapter)

What I am doing here is :

I have created 3 different type adapter and based on need it is trying to merge 9 adapter in a loop and all these 9 adapter can of of one of the 3 types we have.

All adapters are merged to RecyclerViewMergeAdapter but at some point 
it is crashing

Also Notice : IF all my sub adapter contains 3 or less items then it works fine but if my sub adapters contains more than 3 to 20 items then it crashes.

Please let me know if someone of have seen this issue and found any solution to this.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: called detach on an already detached child ViewHolder{7c7ecfb position=2 id=-1, oldPos=-1, pLpos:-1 scrap tmpDetached no parent}
  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$4.detachViewFromParent(RecyclerView.java:605)
  at android.support.v7.widget.ChildHelper.detachViewFromParent(ChildHelper.java:284)
  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.detachViewInternal(RecyclerView.java:6473)
  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.detachViewAt(RecyclerView.java:6466)
  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.scrapOrRecycleView(RecyclerView.java:6835)
  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.detachAndScrapAttachedViews(RecyclerView.java:6818)
  at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:532)
  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:2847)
  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3145)
  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16636)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1079)
  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16636)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onLayout(ViewPager.java:1627)
  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16636)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
  at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.layoutChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:1034)
  at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayoutChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:744)
  at android.support.design.widget.ViewOffsetBehavior.onLayoutChild(ViewOffsetBehavior.java:42)
  at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onLayoutChild(AppBarLayout.java:1180)
  at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayout(CoordinatorLayout.java:757)
  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16636)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16636)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1743)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1586)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1495)
  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16636)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
  at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onLayout(PhoneWindow.java:2678)
  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16636)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2171)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1931)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1107)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6013)
  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:606)
  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Answer (score 0):

OK it was issue in my code

issue is discussed and [fixed here :](https://github.com/martijnvdwoude/recycler-view-merge-adapter/issues/4#issuecomment-250506056)